# Remove duplicated commits after bad rebase, without messing with merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-rebase

I started an interactive rebase to amend all commits of the repo with a specific prefix (all in the same branch). It did not succeed because of old conflicts but I've made the error to push anyway (without aborting). Now, all my commits are duplicated, and I would like to remove them.

The problem is that I try to remove duplicated commits with another interactive rebase, by marking them drop. However the rebase stops at every commit creating a conflict, although the next commit already solves the conflict.

Is it possible to tell rebase that all conflicts are solved by following commits ? Alternatively, is there a way to remove all duplicated commits in an automated manner? (i.e. not stopping at every conflict)

--

I read several posts about the removal of duplicated commits, but I did not find how to automatically tackle (already solved) conflicts.
Moreover, -p option seems to be good for this purpose, but it is messing up with the interactive -i option.